# fprintf gives unexpected output while sending it to file

Tags: c, arrays, printf, memset

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char name[50];

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("./account.txt","a+");

  memset(name,'-',50);
  scanf("%s",name);
  printf("%s",name); // i get correctoutput
  fprintf(fp,"%s",name); // I get wrong output
  return 0;
}
```

In my code I have

-- global declaration

`char name[50];`

and in main I use

`memset(name,'-',49);`

and read the value into the string using `scanf`. I am getting two different output's

//assume I give the input as `test`

1. If I use `printf` to print the char array onto the monitor I get proper output as `test`
2. If i use `fprintf` and print the char array onto file I get wrong output, 
   like first 49 characters as '-' followed by a `0` then whatever I type (In this case `test`)
   `-------------------------------------------------0test`

Can someone explain what's happening ? Or how to tackle such problems ?

Comment: Rather than describing what your code does, just post your code.

Comment: When I use the code you have posted (replacing the apostrophe after `return 0` with a semicolon) it produces exactly the same output whether using `printf` or `fprintf`.  Is it possible that your code is not the code here?  Alternatively, have you deleted account.txt before starting (your `"a+"` will add to the end, and perhaps you had the odd string in there earlier?).

Comment: You code is working fine!.

Comment: Try removing your file and run your program again.  You may be seeing output from previous runs since you opened the file in append mode,

Answer (score 1):

```
char name[50];
...
int main()
{
    memset(name, '-', 50);
}
```

Strings in C are characters which are contiguous in memory, followed by a NULL character ('\0') to mark the end of the string. When printing a string, `printf` will print each character in the string until it encounters the NULL byte, then stop.

In this case, the whole string starts off as NULL characters (because it's an un-initialised global), then you overwrite all of the string with '-'. By doing so, there is no longer a NULL terminator to mark the end of the string.

We're now into the land of undefined behaviour. The `printf` call worked because it just so happened that the next bit of storage was a zero in that case, but such behaviour must not be relied upon (again...undefined behaviour).

To fix this, you need to add the null terminator manually, for example:

```
char name[50];
int main()
{
    memset(name, '-', 49); // Note we're not writing to the last byte now!
    name[49] = '\0';
}
```